# What is the SQL query for the below condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

The Sales person enters their daily reports of visits to the companies. The same companies may be visited by the different sales persons.

I want to display company name, sales person name and their no of visits to the company.

The problem with the below query is that, it groups with `company_name` even though it has two more than one sales person. i want to separate it.

```
  SELECT `employee_name`, 
         COUNT(`cid`) 
    FROM `tbl_reports` 
GROUP BY `company_name`
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to group it by `company_name` **and** `employee_name` - just do it.

```
  SELECT `company_name`, 
         `employee_name`, 
         COUNT(`cid`) 
    FROM `tbl_reports` 
GROUP BY `company_name`,
         `employee_name`;
```

Comment: So we have grouped it, can we get the row id's of the grouped row. Thank you.

Comment: I don't follow you. There is no such thing as row id in sql, until you have some column named `row_id`. There is also `row_number` function, but I'm afraid MySQL doesn't have it. Oh, wait, [look here](http://ayushkumarmishra.wordpress.com/2012/03/26/use-row_number-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

Add `companyname` in your query...Because you need to display `companyname`

```
SELECT `companyname`, `employee_name`,COUNT(`cid`) FROM `tbl_reports` 
GROUP BY `company_name`, `employee_name`;
```

## [SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2e6c/1)

Answer (score 0):

```
     `SELECT companyname, employeename,COUNT(cid)
      FROM tbl_reports 
       GROUP BY companyname;`
```

I think also we can use this query and you get individual data by company...only

```
     `SELECT companyname, employeename,COUNT(cid)
      FROM tbl_reports 
       GROUP BY employeename;`
```

Then you can get salesperson total visited company data.